# Does Ubuntu 12.04 supports for B75 boards?

Tags: 12.04, hardware

I want to build a new computer with Intel G840 CPU and Gigabyte B75M-D3H motherboard and install Ubuntu (or Kubuntu)  12.04 64bit on it.

However, I'm worried about whether the chip is too new and whether that Linux Kernel now has support for it.

According to the article
[[Phoronix] Intel Core i7 3770K Ivy Bridge Linux Performance Review](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_corei7_3770k&num=2)
,the Linux kernel is ready to work on the chip.

> Existing Intel Sandy Bridge motherboards/chipsets are compatible with
>   Ivy Bridge processors, but earlier this month Intel launched the new
>   Panther Point chipsets that are already compatible with Linux too: the
>   B75, H77, Z75, Z77, HM75, HM76, UM77, and HM77.

But I didn't find further information or cases about running Ubuntu on the chip.

So,is it OK to run Ubuntu on the board? Do I need to upgrade the kernel to a newer version (3.4 or 3.5 etc.) to get the system more smoothly?

Or should I choose boards with H61 chip?

Thank for your response!

Answer (score 2):

The minimum specifications for running Ubuntu can be identified easily by using Google.

[What are the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu?](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

Ubuntu is a very versatile and is designed run on many machines, and can be easily run on older and weaker machines. It is often used as a solution to speed up the system speed of old computers. However, since your system is new - it should definitely be able to run Ubuntu just fine!

If not, you can always use Lubuntu - a lighter version of Ubuntu for systems with lower specifications.

[What flavour of Ubuntu suits my system best?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivate-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardware)

[Download Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/)

However, as I said - your system should ***indeed*** be able to run Ubuntu!

Answer (score 1):

You should run `Ubuntu` in `Live mode`. Download ubuntu , burn it or create a bootable usb disk.

Boot from it and Then Choose `Try ubuntu without installing` menu item.

It will start ubuntu from cd/usb. No changes in hardware. :)

If everything works out fine you can install it to your hard disk.

`Live mode` is made for that purpose. :)

Comment: Thanks for your response :-) But I haven't get the machine yet, so I can't try it now... I want to confirm the compatibility before buying the machine.